# File Dependent Key Bindings

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have added following piece of code to `Preferences > Key Bindings - User` configruation file in my Sublime Text 3:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "<strong>${0:$SELECTION}</strong>"} },
```

As a result, when user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in editor, current selection is surrounded with HTML tags `<strong>` and `<strong>`.

Is there anyway, I can make this setting file-type depended? I.e. if user is working in `*.txt` or `*.md` file, then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in editor should surround selection with Markdown bold tag (`**`) and, when editing any other type of file (in general or `*.html` files in particular), then to surround with HTML tags, as in above example.

Is this possible in Sublime Text 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the `context` parameter:

```json
"context": [
    {
        "key": "selector",
        "operator": "equal",
        "operand": "source.php"
    }
]
```

> **`selector`** Returns the name of the current [scope](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html?highlight=scope).
>
> **`operator`** [Type of test](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#context-operators) to perform against key‘s value. Defaults to equal.
>
> **`operand`** The result returned by key is tested against this value.
>
> More help see: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html

#### Examples

For recognizing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in HTML only

```json
// bold snippet for html
{ 
    "keys": ["ctrl+b"], 
    "command": "insert_snippet", 
    "args": {"contents": "<strong>${0:$SELECTION}</strong>"},
    "context": [
        {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.html.basic"}
    ]
},
```

For recognizing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in Markdown and plain text:

```json
// bold snippet for markdown and plain text
{ 
    "keys": ["ctrl+b"],
    "command": "insert_snippet", 
    "args": {"contents": "**${0:$SELECTION}**"},
    "context": [
        {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "(text.html.markdown, text.plain)"}
    ]
},
```